# Running Bash commands in Python causing incorrect results due to new line

Tags: python, bash

I'm using Python to run a subprocess of a command that scans a USB drive for viruses using ClamScan, the command works perfectly when executed in the terminal but when I run it within my Python script it creates the temporary output file but the file does not contain the expected results, where as running it directly gives the expected result.

```
cmd = "clamscan -r --infected --no-summary " + drivePath + " > tempout.txt"
clamScan = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True)
```

Looking at the output of clamScan is as follows:

```
clamscan -r --infected --no-summary /media/root/USB 
> tempout.txt
```

tempout.txt is created but is then empty. Running
    clamscan -r --infected --no-summary /media/root/USB > tempout.txt
via the terminal creates the file with 1 line which is the expected result. It appears that running the command via the subprocess function is causing a line return after the variable drivePath, but I'm unsure as to why?

Comment: Check that your drivePath  does not end with a "\n" and remove it if needed

Comment: I don't understand why you redirect output: check_output directly "writes" in the varaible. So you could simply: cmd = "clamscan -r --infected --no-summary " + drivePath  ; output = subprocess.check_output(cmd.split(), shell=True). By the way, check_output requires command and args split in a list, not a single str?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if redirection works using '>' inside python. You can use the subprocess.Popen() function, which allows more control over the input/output. The output from stdout can be redirected to a file for instance:

```
import subprocess, sys

clamscan_cmd="clamscan -r --infected --no-summary {}".format(drivepath)

with open('tmpout.txt', 'w') as tmp_file:
    p=subprocess.Popen(clamscan_cmd.split(), stdout=tmp_file)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    if err or p.returncode != 0:
        print("clamscan failure: \nReturn Code: {}\n Error output: {}".format(p.returncode, err))
        sys.exit(1)
```